# How do I quickly create new instances of complex MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm managing an enterprise web application that uses Amazon's RDS as our database server. Our architecture is such that when a user signs up for a new account we create a brand new database for them in RDS.

The database has around 63 tables, most of which have indexes, and almost all have foreign key constraints. Currently we're creating each new database by executing a large set of sql statements. This takes on average 57 seconds.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I could do this quicker or more efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: you have the query and the explain on the query? and the table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the database creation happening automatically as the user signs up? is the user waiting all this time until everything finishes to get a response ?

If that is the case, then the average time mentioned above is really problematic. I can suggest that you create databases in advance (manually or in your code) and when the user signs up, you only associate him with an available (already created) database. you can have a process watching for available empty databases and creating new ones if the number falls below some specified number.

Comment: This is exactly the solution we came up with and implemented today. It work's pretty good. We have a service on a separate server that will create a certain number of empty databases not tied to any account. Then when the user signs up they simply get assigned one of these databases. Works pretty well!